# How do I aggregate data in a R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
Col A | Col B | Col C
  1       2       3
  2       4       5
  3       1       3
  4       2       3
```

and I want to mutate my dataframe to aggregate Col B and Col C based on groups in col A. The col A groups are <= 2 and >2.

```
Col A | Col B | Col C
 <=2      6      8
  >2      3      6
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `aggregate` + `ifelse` like below

```
aggregate(
  . ~ ColA,
  transform(
    df,
    ColA = ifelse(ColA <= 2, "<=2", ">2")
  ), sum
)
```

which gives

```
  ColA ColB ColC
1  <=2    6    8
2   >2    3    6
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), .(ColA = ifelse(ColA <= 2, "<=2", ">2"))]
   ColA ColB ColC
1:  <=2    6    8
2:   >2    3    6
```

Comment: How would I do this if I wanted to add on all the similar values of column A? Say instead of 1,2,3,4 column A had 1,1,2,2. How would I combined based on the value of column A without manually doing ==1, ==2, ==3, etc

Comment: Also, when running that code, i get the error "Error: unexpected '=' in:"

Comment: @ZeBringer Try `aggregate(.~ColA, df,sum)`